# speed of the light emitted from a fast moving object

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

Would not speed of the light emitted from the front of the fast moving object be the speed of light + the speed of the fast moving object?

Comment: Please look at [relativistic addition of velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity).

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I am travelling on a car at around 60 km/h, and I shine a light, does that mean that the light is travelling faster than the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79331/)

Answer (score 0):

No, light travels at the same speed for all reference frames due to Einstein's theory of relativity. The light would travel away from the fast object at the speed of light to the reference frame of the speeding object, but you would also see the light traveling at the speed of light from a nonmoving reference frame.