# Doppler effect on a WiFi

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, velocity, doppler-effect

If we move in the universe with about 1500 km/s (earth with 30 km/s + sun with 230 km/s in the milky way + milky way....) why there is no Doppler effect on my WiFi when i change the position in the direction and opposite direction of earth direction of travel? And also does the signal arrives faster or respectively slower with 1500 km/s when i change the position in the direction and opposite direction of earth direction of travel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I am travelling on a car at around 60 km/h, and I shine a light, does that mean that the light is travelling faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79331/)

Comment: No it doesn't answer. I have asked something else.

Comment: The link suggested above should answer but the story is even simpler if you refer to emitter and receiver resident on Earth.